# Join two Network.Wai.Application

Tags: haskell, servant, haskell-wai

i am using `servant` and `Network.Wai.Application.Static` for json api and static file serving respectively. I want to join these two [Application](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application) such that if `staticApp` fails to serve, request should go to `jsonApp`.

I tried finding out and read how `websocketsOr` has done it.[WebsocketsOr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-websockets-3.0.1.1/docs/src/Network-Wai-Handler-WebSockets.html#websocketsOr)

I finally wrote :

```
app :: NW.Application -> NW.Application -> NW.Application
app staticApp apiApp req respond =
  staticApp req (\ response ->
                  do
                    if (Status.statusCode . NW.responseStatus $ response) < 300
                    then respond response
                    else apiApp req respond)
```

But it seems like someone else (wai itself) would have done it, handling many possible cases.. But i am not able to find.

What are the edges cases i am missing (exceptions ?? ) and what other api can i use to do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this on `#servant` channel and `alpounet` told me about `servant Raw` that allows to put our own `Application` handler. They even have a `serveDirectory` api as well :)

```
import qualified Servant as S
import Servant ((:>), (:<|>))

type JobApi = "job" :> "status" :> S.Capture "id" ST.JobId :> S.Get '[S.JSON] ST.JobStatus
         :<|> "job" :> S.ReqBody '[S.JSON] ST.JobPostBody :> S.Post '[S.JSON] ST.JobId
         :<|> "job" :> S.Capture "id" ST.JobId :> S.Get '[S.JSON] ST.JobResult
         :<|> S.Raw

serverRouter :: ST.Server -> S.Server JobApi
serverRouter server = statusGet
    S.:<|> jobPost
    S.:<|> jobGet
    S.:<|> S.serveDirectory "assets"
  where 
    -- ... so on
```